# Get format ABC-XXX-XXX using regex

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have the data as follows

```
CVE-2011-0573,
CVE-2011-0606,
(CVE-2011-0565)
CVE-2011-0598,
CVE-2011-0593.
((CVE-2011-0593.)
```

I need only to get the format "`ABC-XXX-XXX`". TheRegEx pattern I am using is "`[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3,10}`".

Plus there is a method written in C#

```
public String RemoveChars(String message)
{
    // The pattern for an expression
    String charPattern = "[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3,10}";
    // Create a regex object with the pattern
    Regex objRegExp = new Regex(charPattern);
    // Replace unwanted char by empty string - TO BE FIXED(?)
    message = objRegExp.Replace(message, String.Empty);
    // Return the message without unwanted chars
    return message;
}
```

So if I run this code now, for "`CVE-2011-0573,`" it returns "`,`" and not "`CVE-2011-0573`".

Could you please help me to fix that C# code so it works the way the result is "`CVE-2011-0573`"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would you think It'd return anything else? You're deleting all occurences of your regex pattern in the message with `Replace` method.

Comment: Well you're *explictly* replacing the bit that matches the message with an empty string. How did you expect that to work? I suspect you just want to *match* the message against your regex, and return the matching value...

Comment: @Tarec - I would not, I am aware of that. That's why I'd need advice what method should I use here so it works in the correct way. I am not C programmer.

Comment: @Dnac, you are asking for `ABC-XXX-XXX`, but then it will result in a loss of data as the data is in the format of `ABC-XXXX-XXXX`

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @DNac bear in mind, that `C` != `C#`.

Comment: I am aware of that, see the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
public String RemoveChars(String message)
        {
            // The pattern for an expression
            String charPattern = @"[A-Z]{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}";
            // Create a regex object with the pattern
            message = Regex.Match(message, charPattern).Value;
            // Return the message without unwanted chars
            return message;
        }
```

Also, if you need multiple matches, use `Regex.Matches`

Comment: Nice, this seems to be working great. Thank you. I just replaced your RegEx with my one as the number of digits may vary. I assume it wont cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

use `objRegExp.Match(message)` to get your match.

or in your example:

```
string output = "";
var matches = objRegExp.Matches(message);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    output+=match;
}
return output;
```

to handle multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: [CLICK](http://www.rubular.com/r/PSBI2sE8Ko)

this should work:

```
   String charPattern ="[.,()]"
```